# Select pair of rows values by specific rule for other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, timestamp

Trying to understand how can I do from that:

---

```
|id|         timestamp        |   type  |
|--|--------------------------|---------|
|11|2018-10-02 15:57:07.000000|  open   |
|11|2018-10-02 16:48:51.000000|  closed |
|11|2018-10-05 08:59:27.000000|  open   |
|11|2018-10-05 09:59:18.000000|  closed |
```

---

that:

```
|id|          open_ts         |         closed_ts        |
|--|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|11|2018-10-02 15:57:07.000000|2018-10-02 16:48:51.000000|
|11|2018-10-05 08:59:27.000000|2018-10-05 09:59:18.000000|
```

I made a "self-join" with the condition on the type.
Here there is one rule: after the "open" should always be "closed". It can not be "open" until it was "closed".
My best result is:

```
|id|          open_ts         |         closed_ts        |
|--|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|11|2018-10-02 15:57:07.000000|2018-10-02 16:48:51.000000|
|11|2018-10-02 15:57:07.000000|2018-10-05 09:59:18.000000|
|11|2018-10-05 08:59:27.000000|2018-10-02 16:48:51.000000|
|11|2018-10-05 08:59:27.000000|2018-10-05 09:59:18.000000|

select z.id id, z.timestamp open_ts, o.timestamp closed_ts
from temp_event z
       join temp_event o
         on z.id=o.id
where z.type='open' and o.type='closed'
```

Also, I tried to use distinct on (id)*, but I got wrong interval value:

```
|id|          open_ts         |         closed_ts        |
|--|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|11|2018-10-02 15:57:07.000000|2018-10-02 16:48:51.000000|
|11|2018-10-05 08:59:27.000000|2018-10-02 16:48:51.000000|
```

* from additional table. This id exists in two copies for one id in presented table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the window function `row_number()` to designate the pairs:

```
with temp_rn as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id, type order by timestamp) as rn
    from temp_event
)
select t1.id, t1.timestamp as open_ts, t2.timestamp as close_ts
from temp_rn t1
join temp_rn t2 
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.rn = t2.rn and t1.type > t2.type

 id |       open_ts       |      close_ts       
----+---------------------+---------------------
 11 | 2018-10-02 15:57:07 | 2018-10-02 16:48:51
 11 | 2018-10-05 08:59:27 | 2018-10-05 09:59:18
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select  id, timestamp as open_ts, closed_ts
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) filter (where type = 'closed') over (partition by id order by timestamp) as closed_ts
      from t
     ) t
where type = 'open';
```

Comment: Im using postgres 10.6. Im not sure how to use 'lead' and many other things, but my console says there's syntax error near 'filter where' :(